# Taking Screen shot continuously without slow down the PC - C#

Tags: c#, screenshot

I have to capture a screen shot continuously after every 250 milliseconds for my program (Similar to Netmeeting). I used the following code:

```
Image CaptureScreenShot()
{
    bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    return bmpScreenshot;
}
```

To capture the screenshot but it slow the performance of the PC. Where, Netmeeting do not.
Is there any way to get screen shot without slowing the PC?
Code sample will be appreciated

Comment: Is this intended for streaming?

Comment: How are you calling this method?  Do you really need to take a screenshot 4 times every second which is on average 240 times a minute and 14,400 times an hour.  You sure this is how Netmeeting does it, the fact Netmeeting does not cause your performance to drop, tells me your wrong.

Comment: @Farid-ur-Rahman - I do not increase a questions reputation if I do not feel the quality is good.  Asking to up vote it means I will simply down vote it for being poor.

Comment: @Farid-ur-Rahman, I'm pretty sure that is why everyone down voted your question.  Do not request votes.  Period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't find a basic answer here. They use much more involved mechanisms for detecting changes on the screen and sending them. 
Check out how terminal svcs work - 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755399%28WS.10%29.aspx

ideally you are hooking into the GUI and monitoring events, etc. much more advanced than simply screen scraping. If you want to look at less advanced code check out http://www.tightvnc.com